Telegram Bot API — стратегии при сетевых ошибках
Допустим, нужно сделать сервер, использующий webhook, и через Telegram Bot API этот сервер в ответ на команду должен показать ровно одно сообщение.
Как я вижу: приходит Update, и сервер открывает соединение к API и использует sendMessage, тем самым отправляя сообщение.
Но, допустим, Telegram Bot API получает сообщение, показывает его, и после этого соединение разрывается. Сервер, отправивший запрос, теперь не знает, выполнен он или нет. Если повторно делать запрос, то будет дубликат.
Как сервер должен действовать в таких ситуациях?

Очевидно, нужно реализовывать идемпотентность. Например, каждому сообщению задаётся некий идентификатор. Этот id временно хранится. Когда приходит новое сообщение, проверяется, нет ли такого айдишника среди уже обработанных.

@AlexanderPetrov я это понимаю но в Telegram Bot API не вижу подобного, сервер управляющий ботом не получает Update на собственный sendMessage
